# Spring Boot JUnit Mockito Specification giving null object

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a problem about writing a Junit with Mockito for Specification in Spring Boot.

I get null result of the bookListResponseResult after defining a bookRepository within when.

How can I fix it?

Here is the method inside the service.

```
public List<BookResponse> searchByTitle(String title) {
       return bookRepository.findAll(BookSearchSpecification.search(title))
               .stream()
               .map(BookListService::response)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Here is the response shown below.

```
private static Response response(Book book) {
   return Response.builder().title(book.getTitle())
                .build();
}
```

Here is the JUnit test method shown below.

```
@Test
    void searchByTitle() {

        // given - precondition or setup
        Response response1 = Response.builder()
                .title("Book Title")
                .build();

        Response bookResponse2 = Response.builder()
                .title("Book Title")
                .build();

        List<BookResponse> bookListResponse = Arrays.asList(bookResponse1,bookResponse2);

        Category category = Category.builder().name("Category 1").build();

        Request saveBookRequest1 = Request.builder()
                .title("Book Title")
                .build();

        Request saveBookRequest2 = Request.builder()
                .title("Book Title")
                .build();

        Book book1 = Book.builder().category(category)
                .title(saveBookRequest1.getTitle())
                .build();

        Book book2 = Book.builder().category(category)
                .title(saveBookRequest2.getTitle())
                .build();

        when(
                bookRepository.findAll(any(Specification.class))
        ).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(book1,book2));

        List<Response> bookListResponseResult = bookListService.searchByTitle("Book Title"); // return null 
        assertEquals(bookListResponse.get(0).getTitle(), bookListResponseResult.get(0).getTitle());
        assertEquals(bookListResponse.get(1).getTitle(), bookListResponseResult.get(1).getTitle());

    }
```

Here is the result shown below of bookListResponseResult.

```
Response(id=null, title=null)
Response(id=null, title=null)
```

Comment: Try replacing ‘saveBookRequest1.getTitle()‘ with static value. Also for receiving answers try to provide more info by posting the full implementation of your test class and your ‘Request‘ class.

Comment: @Mo_- It didn't help me after replacing ‘saveBookRequest1.getTitle()‘ with static value. I already shared all information about it.

Comment: I‘d put some breakpoints to debug what’s going on. Check builder of your ‘Book‘ and ‘Response‘ classes are working properly and their getters returning correct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I revised the code shown below, the issue disappeared.

Change

```
List<BookResponse> bookListResponse = Arrays.asList(bookResponse1,bookResponse2);
```

To

```
List<Response> bookListResponse = Arrays.asList(bookResponse1,bookResponse2);
```